# AVD Eclipse_ Cannot create new AVD_OK greyed out

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I know this question has been asked multiple times on this and other sites but I still have no luck with dealing with this. So before I uninstall everything I want to see if there are anymore opinions.

Like the others I am trying to create (this computers) first AVD but have been presented with a greyed out 'OK' button. I have installed all of the latest packages, including the latest ARM package. I have restarted the software and computer to no avail. I have used AVD before but this is the first time it haden't worked for me.

Helpful opinions will be welcomed.

Comment: Also to add I have tried to create the application outside of eclipse using the monitor.bat file

Comment: why not you simply download complete one package of Eclipse ADT with android SDK?

Comment: Yeh i did that...thought it may had been an issue with downloading a stand alone version but I have redownloaded and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

You must have everything selected, that includes at least 5 things:
a AVD name, a device, a Target API Level, a CPU, a Skin, the memory is mostly automatically filled and the SD Card is optional, so it looks like this:

[image: Creating an AVD]